# How to pass mock object to another mock object constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

```
    /// <summary>
    ///A test for ReverseName
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    public void ReverseNameTest()
    {
        Mock<IEntityName> entityName = new Mock<IEntityName>();
        entityName.SetupProperty(x => x.FirstName, "John");
        entityName.SetupProperty(x => x.LastName, "T.");

        var p = new Person(entityName.Object);

        string expected = "Your reverse name is T. John"; 
        string actual;
        actual = p.ReverseName();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

//Person Class

```
  public Person(IEntityName EntityName)
    {
        this.EntityName = EntityName;
    }
```

Is it possible to mock Person class as well in the TestMehod or do I have to create an instance of Person as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can. Rhino mock supports that, not sure about Moq, but i think you can do that as well

Take a look at this thread.
[Passing Moq mock-objects to constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011572/passing-moq-mock-objects-to-constructor)

[Mocking objects with Moq when constructor has parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414704/mocking-objects-with-moq-when-constructor-has-parameters)

Comment: I did look into the first link before writing this question. I'm looking into the second link using Mock.of....

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. var p = new Mock<Person>(entityName.Object)